# Sealed objects and checking type of an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

**Background to this question**

I recently started to get into test-driven development (TDD) in Javascript using karma and Jasmine. I would like to develop proper tests along with good code that takes care of all eventualities. This also means for me to check for the right types of objects inside my test cases.

**Current problem**

JSON Data returned from an AJAX call should be matched against an object to make sure the right data is returned. To do so I came up with the following code (simplified);

```
var MyClass = {};
Object.defineProperties(MyClass, {
  Key: {
    value: '',
    writable: true
  }
});

var sealed = Object.seal(MyClass);
try {
  $.extend(sealed, jsonResponse);
  return sealed;
} catch(e) {
  return false;
}
```

This works as expected and in case any extra properties are part of the JSON `false` will be returned. So far, so good. What I would like to also do is to check if the returned data is of the right "type". I could do so by using a function instead of an object:

```
var MyClass = function() {
  this.key= '123';
}; 
var myClass = new MyClass();
console.log(myClass instanceof MyClass); // True
```

But I can't come up with an idea how to combine both so I can both make sure that no attributes are added to the object and also to be able to check for the right "Class". In the first case `typeof sealed` would always yield "object".

**Restrictions**

I need to also support Internet Explorer 11 so I can't use `class MyClass { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the combined version would be:

```
// The "class"
var MyClass = function(data) {
  // Create all the allowed properties
  this.key = '123';

  // Seal the instance so others can't be created
  Object.seal(this);

  // If data was supplied, apply it
  if (data) {
    $.extend(this, data);
  }
}; 

// The instance that you'd use, note passing in the parsed JSON daa
var myClass = new MyClass(jsonResponse);
console.log(myClass instanceof MyClass); // true
```

Live Example:

```js
// The "class"
var MyClass = function(data) {
  // Create all the allowed properties
  this.key = '123';

  // Seal the instance so others can't be created
  Object.seal(this);

  // If data was supplied, apply it
  if (data) {
    $.extend(this, data);
  }
};

var jsonResponse = {
  key: "456"
};

// The instance that you'd use, note passing in the parsed JSON daa
var myClass = new MyClass(jsonResponse);
console.log(myClass instanceof MyClass); // true
console.log(myClass.key);                // "456"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That will throw an error if `jsonResponse` contains properties that `MyClass` doesn't allow, because trying to create a new property on a sealed object throws an error. You've said in the comments that's what you want (which makes sense).

If it *weren't* what you want, you could write your own function to copy the properties rather than using `$.extend`:

```
function applyData(obj, data) {
    var own = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj);
    Object.keys(data).filter(own).forEach(function(key) {
        obj[key] = data[key];
    });
}
```

(Or use an `in` check if you want to allow inherited properties — for instance, accessor properties — to be set.)

(You could just use an `if` in the `forEach` callback rather than `.filter(own)`.)

Then use that function instead of `$.extend`.

Live Example:

```js
// The function to apply the data
function applyData(obj, data) {
    var own = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj);
    Object.keys(data).filter(own).forEach(function(key) {
        obj[key] = data[key];
    });
}

// The "class"
var MyClass = function(data) {
  // Create all the allowed properties
  this.key = '123';

  // Seal the instance so others can't be created
  Object.seal(this);

  // If data was supplied, apply it
  if (data) {
    applyData(this, data);
  }
}; 

var jsonResponse = {
  key: "456",
  extra: "will be ignored"
};

// The instance that you'd use, note passing in the parsed JSON daa
var myClass = new MyClass(jsonResponse);
console.log(myClass instanceof MyClass); // true
console.log(myClass.key);                // "456"
console.log(myClass.extra);              // undefined
```

But your approach of having an error makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great example! I haven't tested this yet but I know it really fits well into what I wanted. Regarding your comment about throwing an error: that would have been perfectly acceptable (in my posted code I therefor added a try/catch block around the `$.extend()`) because malformed data should result in discarding the received data altogether.

Comment: @SaschaM78 - Ah! Yeah, throwing an error is better, isn't it? Because then it flags up the mis-match between the front-end and back-end, so you can fix it. Nice one.